# Re-export qualified - how to solve it nowadays, any solution?

Tags: haskell, module

I have exactly the same issue as described in this question [Re-export qualified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385195/re-export-qualified)

> ```
> module Foo.A where
>
> foo = 42
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> module Foo.B where
>
> foo = 12
> ```
>
> and you want to write a super module
>
> ```
> module Foo (
>       module Foo.A
>     , module Foo.B
>     ) where
>
> import Foo.A
> import Foo.B
> ```
>
> which re-exports those modules, you would get a name clash.

It was asked 5 years ago, I suppose there might have been some changes since then. Have there been any? If not, there's still no solution for that?

I do **not** consider Lens for resolving it.

**UPDATE**:

There can be plenty of the functions `foo` in each module (foo1, foo2, etc) and I want to use them from both modules. There can also be `data`s with the same member names in each module, after all.

So hiding isn't a solution.

Comment: > There can be plenty of the functions foo in each module (foo1, foo2, etc) and I want to use them from both modules. There can also be datas with the same member names in each module, after all.  If it's really the case and you don't want to hide anything. The only solution is to import both modules qualified and not try to create an AB module exporting both

Comment: @mb14, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: FWIW, I feel like it would have been more appropriate to add a “current answers are outdated” bounty to the old question rather than ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *new* solution, but there is still a solution.
First you, as only one `foo` can be exported you have to decide which one you want to export as the bare `foo`. Then you just need to hide and alias the other one.

```
module Foo (
  module Foo.A
, module Foo.B
, bFoo
) where

import Foo.A
import Foo.B hiding (foo)
import qualified B as B

bFoo = B.foo
```

Ok, it's not really elegant but it's a workaround if you really have to.

Comment: **First you, as only one foo can be exported you have to decide which one you want to export as the bare foo** - I want to use both and there can be plenty of them.

Comment: I mean only one foo can be exported as bare `foo` (whatever the language). I understand you would like `A.foo` and `B.foo` but that two different names and none of them are bare `foo`. So you can have one `foo` but the other needs to have another name (example `Bfoo` or `B_foo` as `B.foo` is not possible).

Comment: That's obvious. But the question is how to import them qualified or something.